# javascript Dynamic function arguments

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

how to setup to use function arguments dynamically, i have tried many method and it doesn't work properly. Hope someone can help me, Thank you very much.

Function:

```
function initDropdown(type, placement, trigger, strategy, functions) {
    tippy('[data-cg-toggle="' + type + '"]', {
        zIndex: 99999,
        interactive: true,
        placement: placement,
        allowHTML: true,
        trigger: trigger,
        popperOptions: {
            strategy: strategy,
        },
        functions
    });
}
```

Init Functions

```
initDropdown('dropdown', 'bottom-end', 'click', 'fixed', {
    content(reference) {
        return content;
    },
    onShown(instance) {
        $($(instance)[0].reference).addClass('dropdown-toggled');
    },
    onHidden(instance) {
        $($(instance)[0].reference).removeClass('dropdown-toggled');
    }
});

initDropdown('dropdown', 'bottom-end', 'click', 'fixed', {
    onShown(instance) {
        var content = $($(instance)[0].reference).parent().children('.dropdown-menu')[0].innerHTML;
        $($(instance)[0].reference).addClass('dropdown-toggled');
        instance.setContent(content);
    },
    onHidden(instance) {
        $($(instance)[0].reference).removeClass('dropdown-toggled');
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Javascript Object In This Case

While Declaring Your Function:

```
function myFunc (options = {}) {
  if(typeof options === 'object') {
    let a = options.type;
    console.log(a)
    return true
  }
  throw new Error("Oops.. MyFunc Accepts only Objects!")
}
```

And While Calling It:

```
myFunc({
  type: 'number',
  etc: '1', // you can add as many values as you want and access it in the function.
})
```

You Can Learn More About It [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Object.assign({}, { ...options... }, functions)
```

or, as tagged [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)

```
$.extend({}, { ...options... }, functions)
```

Example:

```
function initDropdown(type, placement, trigger, strategy, functions) {
  tippy('[data-cg-toggle="' + type + '"]',
    Object.assign({}, {
        zIndex: 99999,
        interactive: true,
        placement: placement,
        allowHTML: true,
        trigger: trigger,
        popperOptions: {
          strategy: strategy,
        }
      },
      functions
    });
}
```

Comment: seem not working.